# Met java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. Could I need to copy ".so" to all "so folder"?

Tags: android, exception, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I met the exception as follow. It means that it can not find "libweibosdkcore.so" which I store in "armeabi" folder. Do I need to copy to all the folder?

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn&#x27;t load weibosdkcore: findLibrary returned null
```

My folder structure as follow,

JniLibs：

arm64-v8a

```
  liblocSDK5.so
```

armeabi

```
 liblocSDK5.so

 libmsc.so

 libweibosdkcore.so
```

x86

```
 liblocSDK5.so
```

and so on.

Comment: What kind of device is this happening on? A non-ARM device? If the x86 and arm64-v8a locSDK5 libraries have dependencies on webosdkcore then you'll need to have x86 and arm64-v8a builds of it in the respective folders. They can't use the ARM one

Comment: Maybe a non-Arm device. The libweibosdkcore.so is general. Should I need to copy it to other folder like x86?

Comment: Copying won't work. You can't use the armeabi version for x86.